Python.Runtime.PythonException: ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush''
Using .net 6 i want to use a python script but i always have this exception: Python.Runtime.PythonException: ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush''
I would like  to find a way to execute the script that downloads information from yahoo finance api. I already tried to obtain the df information but i had the same problem that is why i tried to download it as csv
I am trying to download the historical data from yahoofinance api yfinance (Python) in .net. I want to have the close data of a stock. I have already tried to execute this code before in python and it works fine. But when i execute it in .net it always throws the exception.
 public void HistoricalData(string ticker, string start, string end) // Specific method name
        {
            // Establece la variable de entorno PYTHONNET_PYDLL
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", @"dll path");

            // Inicializa el motor de Python
            PythonEngine.Initialize();
            PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();

            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                // create a Python scope
                using (PyModule scope = Py.CreateScope())
                {
                    // create python variables
                    scope.Set("path", new PyString("path"));
                    scope.Set("ticker", new PyString(ticker));
                    scope.Set("start", new PyString(start));
                    scope.Set("end", new PyString(end));
                    // the person object may now be used in Python
                    string code = @"import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
np.savetxt(path, yf.download(ticker, start , end )['Close'].values, delimiter = ';')
";

                    scope.Exec(code);
                }
            }

            // Finaliza el motor de Python
            PythonEngine.Shutdown();
        }```


maybe helpful or related AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush' with pyinstaller [duplicate]

I tried but continue having the problem
